# Array subscription in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Let's say I have an array of elements and in addition to displaying the list in my app, I want to sync the list to the server with `HttpClient`. How can I observe changes to the array? I tried:

```js
@inject(ObserverLocator)
export class ViewModel {

    constructor(obsLoc) {
        this.list = [];
        obsLoc.getObserver(this, 'list');
            .subscribe(li => console.log(li));
    }
}
```

But I got neither error nor log message.

Comment: Would it be enough to observe the list.length ? Would it not be easier to see the changes happening ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`getObserver` returns a property observer which will notify you when the `ViewModel` class instance's `list` property changes.  This will only happen when you assign a new value to the `list` property, ie `this.list = [1,2,3]`.  If you're not assigning new values to the `list` property and instead are mutating the value of the property via `push`, `pop`, `splice`, etc, you'll want to use an array observer.  Use the `ObserverLocator`'s `getArrayObserver` method- it takes one parameter, the array you want to observe:

```javascript
import {ObserverLocator} from 'aurelia-binding'; // or from 'aurelia-framework'

@inject(ObserverLocator)
export class ViewModel {

    constructor(obsLoc) {
        this.list = [];
        obsLoc.getArrayObserver(this.list);
            .subscribe(splices => console.log(splices));
    }
}
```

## October 2015 update

The ObserverLocator is Aurelia's internal "bare metal" API.  There's now a public API for the binding engine that could be used:

```js
import {BindingEngine} from 'aurelia-binding'; // or from 'aurelia-framework'

@inject(BindingEngine)
export class ViewModel {
  constructor(bindingEngine) {
    this.list = []; // any Array, Map and soon Set will be supported

    // subscribe
    let subscription = bindingEngine.collectionObserver(this.list)
      .subscribe(splices => console.log(splices));

    // be sure to unsubscribe **later**
    subscription.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: has the syntax here changed at all?

Comment: we never added something simple like import { observe } from 'aurelia-framework'; observe(anything, callback)?

Comment: Does this still work (october update) as I can'seem to get the collectionObserver callback to work but your earlier example works fine?

Comment: should work- if you want to open a new question with some specifics about your issue, I can look into it.

Comment: Ah sorry found my issue. I am calling dispose in the constructor (same code you posted). duh! Sorry

Comment: Doesn't fire when operating on an empty array.

Comment: What if I want to assign a new value to the list property

Comment: @Tuhin You will need to dispose of the collectionObserver first and then re-attach it to the property.